# Why does a request made on postman give the desired response but the exact one made on the browser fails?

Tags: node.js, express, react-hooks, axios, express-session

So i am working on a laundry booking project, i am using node js and express js, i have been able to retrieve data from other API endpoints but this one just does not work, i want to implement data persistence using express-sessions, so when the user moves to the next page the details are retrieved from the former, i post the data and store it in the session, i also create a unique Id and then send that back to the client which is added to the url as a query parameter and then i retrieve it from the server using a get request, and that is where it fails.

```
route.post("/step1", async (req, res) => {
    const bookingData = req.body;

    const bookingId = generateBookingId();
    console.log(bookingId)

    req.session.bookings = req.session.bookings ? req.session.bookings : {};
    req.session.bookings[bookingId] = bookingData;

    if(req.session.bookings){
        console.log(req.session.bookings);
    }


    res.send(bookingId);
})
```

This here is is the code to send the bookingId back to the user, this works fine.

After posting this is the code i used to move to the new page using the useNavigate of the react-router-dom

```
const { mutate: bookingMutate, data } = useMutation(addBookings);
    if(data?.data){
        navigate(`/services/${serviceId}/step2?bookingId=${data?.data}`);
    }
```

Based on what i see from the failed request the the data is pulled successfully from the useMutation hook of the useQuery package

Now in the page to display this data this is what i have
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
const bookingId = query.get('bookingId');

```
function getSessionData(bookingId) {
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:9000/api/bookings/step2?bookingId=${bookingId}`);
}

const { data } = useQuery("sessionData", getSessionData(bookingId));
console.log(data?.data)
```

And the Node js code for handling this request

```
route.get("/step2", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { bookingId } = req.query;
      const bookingData = req.session.bookings?.[bookingId];
  
      if (!bookingData) {
        return res.status(404).send("The session data does not exist");
      }
    
      res.send(bookingData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error retrieving booking data:", error);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred while retrieving booking data");
    }
});
```

Then when i make a request though i have debugged and logged several details and i confirmed that is it indeed being stored in the session, i used postman and everything works fine but this particular one just fails and returns the 404 error saying "The session data does not exist" but the one made on postman works fine, i have also used the cors package to make sure i can get data from the APIs and other get request works just this one that fails

Comment: Are you sure the user response and request is going to the same session?  log the request session id - and probably postman autocompletes and uses session id for the following requests but browser do not - and you need to include it in the request using axios (like ,,with credentials'')

Answer (score 0):

you need return json object

```
route.get("/step2", async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { bookingId } = req.query;
  const bookingData = req.session.bookings?.[bookingId];

  if (!bookingData) {
    return res.status(404).json("The session data does not exist");
  }

  res.json(bookingData);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error retrieving booking data:", error);
  res.status(500).json("An error occurred while retrieving booking data");
}
```

});

```
route.post("/step1", async (req, res) => {
const bookingData = req.body;

const bookingId = generateBookingId();
console.log(bookingId)

req.session.bookings = req.session.bookings ? req.session.bookings : {};
req.session.bookings[bookingId] = bookingData;

if(req.session.bookings){
    console.log(req.session.bookings);
}


res.json(bookingId);
```

})